# XFCE4 Empty Volume Control Applet

Tags: xfce, volume-control, indicator-sound

In Xfce4.10 on the panel I put the Indicator Applet. It always showed me the volume control and network icons. I updated to 13.10, cleaned some stuff, removed some orphaned package, and I notice that now the volume control applet is showing mute and if I click on it there is an empty dropdown menu like 10x5 px. It has become completely useless. So what should I reinstall or change to get the controls to work?

Comment: Yes, I have this problem too. Unfortunately, it looks like this problem will not be fixed anytime soon even though it's marked of high importance. It's been around for 3 months and still hasn't been fixed yet :( Pretty sad given that sound control seems like a core feature. There are workarounds on the bug report page, but I'm just going to wait for the fix. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1208204

Answer (score 2):

Now it's SOLVED: The path to the indicator-sound-service is wrong.

In my case this is in `/usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service`
So we have to modify `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service`

If you look in the file, there is another path so the emptiness is normal.. Change the path (use root access) to gain write permission to the file.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service
```

and change the `Exec` path to `/usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service`.

Comment: Mark your own answer as the answer.  Do not edit the title to say "solved"